# Access Phone Lock in Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-ndk

I want to check if the user entered wrong password on blackberry 10 device phone lock. Is there a way to do so or shall I make a custom phone lock App and do same? I am avoiding custom phone lock app as I don't have any idea about how will it replace inbuilt phone lock. (I am a beginner coding on BB Native SDK for platform 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API that would inform your application if a user entered the wrong password when trying to unlock their BlackBerry.

Comment: hi @msohm help this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267298/error-starting-app-name-error-loading-module-appname-verify-error